# Conditional Axis in Lattice R

Tags: r, if-statement, plot, graph, lattice

Here it comes a challenge. The target is to give format (bold/regular) to the y-axis in a dotplot under de condition of variable "Z" being higher/lower sd. I have already been able to introduce the formatting so I am now struggling on how to introduce the logic test.

```
   #dataframe
d<-data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:26],b=rnorm(26,50,10),c=rnorm(26,50,1))
#dotplot
dotplot(a~b,d,col="blue",pch=16,
        #simple plot comparing two vectors
        panel = function(x,col,y,...){
  panel.dotplot(x,col="blue",y,...)
  panel.xyplot(x=d$c,col="darkblue",y,...)
  mins=NULL
  maxs=NULL
  #a line showing the difference between "measures"
  for(i in 1:nrow(d)){
    mins[i]<-min(d$c[i],d$b[i])
    maxs[i]<-max(d$c[i],d$b[i])
  }
  panel.segments(x0=mins,y0=as.numeric(y),
                 x1=maxs,y1=as.numeric(y),col="red")
},
#the challenge of the conditional Y-axis
yscale.components = function(...){ 
  temp <- yscale.components.default(...) 
  loc <- temp$left$labels$at 
  print( temp$left$labels$labels <-   
           sapply( temp$left$labels$labels, 
                   function(x) if(a> x){ 
                     as.expression(bquote( bold(.(x)))) 
                   }else{ 
                     as.expression(bquote(.(x)))} )) 
  temp },
#a legend
key = list(columns=2, 
           points=list(pch=16,col=c("blue","darkblue")),
           text=list(c("measure","fitted"))))
```

I would like to consider this an advance code, so let me hear your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code mainly in sapply() to introduce the logic test. I use "bold" when abs( b - c ) > sd( b - c ) (abs(b-c) is each row's value but sd(b-c) is common value). sapply() gives a label in sequence and we can pick a row having the lavel out by subset() (There're other methods to do it, for example d[d$a == x, ] ). This time, subset(~) means one row. Using this in if (), you can do some logic tests. 
[Edit] Other modified parts are panel.segments (can write more simply) and "loc" (delete because of not using).

```
#dataframe
d<-data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:26],b=rnorm(26,50,10),c=rnorm(26,50,1))
# calculate sd
b_sd <- with( d, sd(b-c) )
#dotplot
dotplot(a~b,d,col="blue",pch=16,
        #simple plot comparing two vectors
        panel = function(x,col,y,...){
          panel.dotplot(x,col="blue",y,...)
          panel.xyplot(x=d$c,col="darkblue",y,...)
## can draw the difference lines more simply
          panel.segments( x, as.numeric(y), d$c, as.numeric(y), col="red" )
        },
## the conditional Y-axis (if abs(b - c) > sd, use "bold")
        yscale.components = function(...){ 
          temp <- yscale.components.default(...) 
          print( temp$left$labels$labels <-   
                   sapply( temp$left$labels$labels,  
## sapply() gives a label in sequence and we can pick one row having the lavel out by subset().
                           function(x) {
                             sub  <- subset(d, d$a == x)
                             if( abs( sub$b - sub$c ) > b_sd ) 
                             {
                               as.expression(bquote( bold(.(x))))
                             } else { 
                               as.expression(bquote(.(x))) 
                             }
                           } )) 
          temp },
        #a legend
        key = list(columns=2, 
                   points=list(pch=16,col=c("blue","darkblue")),
                   text=list(c("measure","fitted"))))
```

[image: plot]